# Column only show one line for multi-line string

Tags: string-manipulation, column

```
Column[{"abc"}]
```

shows

```
abc
```

But

```
Column[{"a\nb\nc"}]
```

only shows

```
a
```

Why is that? How to make `Column` show complete multi-line string?

Comment: I get the expected output with v13.1.0 on windows. Maybe try with another stylesheet

Comment: @Coolwater OK, I use 12.2, So I think this might be a bug, however already fixed now in 13.1 : )